# Foursquare: check if a user visited a city

Tags: geolocation, foursquare

I was just wondering...Is it possible to check whether a specific user has checked in a specific city?

For example, if John has previously checked in at some restaurants in London and Paris, is it possible to test from within my application if John has visited something in London or Paris?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, within reason.

- The user authenticates via OAuth2
- You produce a number of recents to the checkin history https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins.html - will probably need to use offset and limit to explore ALL of their check-ins
- You will want to write an algorithm to figure out what 'city' means to you - perhaps X miles within the lat/long of the city center? For more detail, use a GeoCode API such as Google's or Bing's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

Comment: Thought about that, but I needed something more precise. I need to check whether the user has checked in a city any time in the past, not only from the recent history, and I need to be sure whether the venue is within a city or not (radius from city center is pretty tricky - it is not always a circle and it varies from one city to another).

Comment: The recent checkins take an offset/limit set of parameters so that you can walk through the entire history. Then just use a Geocode API to actually see if that location falls into a city set of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Will definitely try it, but I will let this question open for any other different ideas. Thank you again!